# Javascript /Extjs 4 String Compare

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I want to compate two string in javascript, and need to find the exact position where is different from other string.

e.g.

```
StingA= "a;b;c;"
StringB="a;bc;"
```

Now from the above StringB is different from StringA at postion 3 .. i.e. ";" is missing at postion 3 [if we start counting a=0,;=1,b=2];

I can not compare character by character, as there might be very big string i.e. StringA="a;b;c;d;e;f;g; ..... "

Can you please provide me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've already profiled an algorithm and determined it was too slow, don't worry about optimizing for performance. Get a working algorithm first, then profile it if you need to.

```
// Returns the index of the first difference between strings a and b,
// or -1 if the strings are equal. Case-sensitive.
function indexOfDiff(a, b) {
    if(a === b) {
        return -1;
    }

    var len = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(a.charAt(i) !== b.charAt(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return len;
}
```

If you absolutely need performance, you could try a heuristic approach based on known positions of ';' (as in your example, if you know it alternates letter and semicolon you might check every other character).

Or for really big strings, you could try a recursive binary search. Split one string in half and check equality with the equivalent substring of the other string. If equal, check the other half. If not equal, split that string in half and repeat the process until you've narrowed down a reasonably sized substring to check. This approach would be much more complicated and error-prone, so try a simpler approach first.